# Trying to access my localhost through a service and getting 301 error?

Tags: php, json, web-services, localhost

[image]im trying to access my localhost i.e. localhost/app and trying to get back some data back in json, this is the php script

```
<?php


 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 

//test if a post request came


if(isset($_POST)) {


    //return a json request

    $contactDetails = array(
  "email" => "some@some.com",
  "twitter" => "@example",

);

echo json_encode($contactDetails);



 }


?>
```

this php file is located at index.php

im trying to access this page using localhost/app page but im getting 301 error in firebug, i dont know why, any help appreciated

**IT WORKS ON THE WEB BROWSER, but not when i try to request the information from somehere else**

Comment: by the way im trying to access my localhost through a service online, and just testing posting requests

Comment: 301 is not an error, it's a permanent redirection to another URL

Comment: `301` is not an error, it's a redirect. My guess is that you are supplying the URI of a directory to the "service" as `hostname.tld/app`, and the web server is sending a 301 redirect to  `hostname.tld/app/`. See if the "service" provides a "follow redirects" or "follow header redirects" option, or add the trailing slash to the URI you are supplying to the "service".

Comment: i put an image at the top see you can see, my localhost is not set port 80 i think

Comment: Try putting `80/job/` in the field, or replace `80` with the appropriate port number. It is the trailing slash on `/job/` that is important.

Comment: ive done that it deosnt work :( , they already put the /job/ for you, thats what it access automatically, you just need give the your localhost, i tried putting http://localhost:80/job in my browser and redirects fine, but it deosnt work from this service. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access a localhost URL from an external (i.e. a live) website? That website would have no way of accessing your localhost unless you've given it a public IP, which I'm assuming you haven't.